# i get an infinite loop when attempting to paginate data

Tags: javascript

I am trying to paginate some data. The limit of results per query are 300, and I can use an offset to get the next page. I am attempting to do this with a while loop like so:

```
async function fetchData (
  contractAddress, 
  tokenID ) 
{

  const url = `https://api.website.io/api/v1/events?asset_contract_address=${contractAddress}&token_id=${tokenID}&offset=0&limit=299`;
    logger.log(url);
    const data = await internalFetch(url, {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-Api-Key': API_KEY,
      },
      method: 'get',
      timeout: 10000, // 10 secs
    })

    var array = data.data.asset_events;
    var offset = 0;
    var tempResponse = array;

    while (tempResponse.length != 0) {
      var urlPage = `https://api.website.io/api/v1/events?asset_contract_address=${contractAddress}&token_id=${tokenID}&offset=${offset}&limit=299`;
      logger.log(urlPage + " url2");
      var nextPage = await internalFetch(urlPage, {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'X-Api-Key': API_KEY,
        },
        method: 'get',
        timeout: 10000, // 10 secs
      })

      tempResponse = nextPage.data.asset_events;
      array.concat(tempResponse);
      offset = array.length;
      logger.log("length " +  offset);
    }

    return array;
}
```

Something in the while loop is not working correctly and running an infinite loop. The  url being queried is the same every time [with the offset at 299], so the same response is being returned and and tempResponse.length is never == 0, ending up with a while loop. Can someone spot the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's this line, where you set the offset:

```
offset = array.length;
```

This is always going to return the same number, assuming there are more than two pages of results.  The first time you will get the array length, and then when you use that in the fetch you will get the results starting at 300.

But that array will also be 299 long, so you send the same offset number and request the second page again.  I think:

```
offset += array.length;
```

should work, although this may repeat the last record from the previous call, in which case you would want `offset += array.length + 1;`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I thought that since I was concatenating the response to the array, THEN setting the offset,  this was being done automatically.

Comment: That's a different issue, then.  array.concat returns a new array with the two merged, if I'm not mistaken, so you'll need to do something like `array = array.concat(array)`.  Then you could get the `array.length` (probably + 1), and that should work.  A heads up, you probably shouldn't use `array` as a variable name, since it could be confused with the keyword, even though that's cased differently.  I would suggest `buffer`, since that's what you're using it for.

Comment: So my suggestion will get you the next page BUT you will end up with an array that doesn't contain all of the results you fetched.

Comment: And you should also use two different variables: `buffer = buffer.concat(results)`, or else you're overwriting the first variable with the new results.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice all that the first time.  I was just focused on the pagination specifically.

Comment: So if i get what youre saying, change array to buffer, where I concat the next page change it to buffer = buffer.concat(results), and then I can get offset using offset = buffer.length + 1

Comment: you need two different arrays: one to take the results you get back, and one to store all the results in.  So you can take your storage array (buffer, if you like) and then append the results array to it.  If you do it that way, then you can use array.length.  Let me go back and make some edits to try to address these things.

Comment: I went back and looked, and I think you have edited the code.  Looking now, does this work for you?  I can't really do a working test because I don't have the api key (and don't give it out, either).

Comment: Sorry, I never followed up on this, yes, you were right about setting `buffer = buffer.concat(results)` and `offset = buffer.length + 1` worked very well. Thanks!